# django-cms apphook + menu

Tags: django, django-cms

django-cms 2.2, django 1.3.1

I'm creating an app called gallery. Gallery has photos inside. (there are many galleries)

I have the following structure:

- cms_app.py - apphook for gallery (needed for gallery details (photos inside gallery) view)
- cms_plugins.py - plugin for galleries list
- menu.py - each gallery has its own page (photos inside galery), we generate menu here
- views.py - a view for gallery details (photos inside)
- urls.py -  // url for apphook to attach for photos inside view, `name=gallery_details`

URL structure:

- `/gallery-list/` - Page for list of galleries
- `/gallery-list/1/` - Photos of pk=1 gallery
- `/another-gallery-list/` - Another page for list of galleries
- `/another-gallery-list/1/` - Photos of pk=1 gallery (the same as `/gallery-list/1/` but different url)

django-cms page structure:

- Page `/gallery-list/` with apphook = gallery app hook + plugin for list of galleries
- Page `/another-gallery-list/` with apphook = gallery app hook + plugin for list of galleries (same but different instances)

Menu:

- Galleries

  - Gallery 1
- Another galleries

  - Gallery 1

Problem: **How do I generate menu for such galleries?**

Currently I'm creating CMSAttachMenu and generating nodes (from model). How do I make urls? I'm trying to use `reverse('gallery_details', args=[self.pk])` (`get_absolute_url` method) but it gives me url: `/galleries/<id>/`. What I want to get is `/gallery-list/1/` and `/another-gallery-list/1/` depending on page which has **apphook** attached.

Here is documentation that I'm using: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.2/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-hooks

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work. I did something similar for a `Project` app when there was a list of projects and also a project detail page.

```
class GalleryMenu(CMSAttachMenu):
    name = _("Gallery Menu")
    def get_nodes(self, request):
        c=itertools.count()
            nav = [
                NavigationNode(
                  _(g.title),
                  reverse("gallery_detail", kwargs={ 'slug' : g.slug }),
                  next(c), parent_id=0
                )
            for i,g in enumerate(Gallery.objects.all()) ]
    return nav
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. Problem is that        `reverse('gallery_details', args=[gallery.pk])` returns `/gallery/1/` and should return `/gallery-list/1/` or `/another-gallery-list/1/`

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`? `gallery` and `gallery-list` should be the Urls of the pages that each gallery is attached to. Then, in your gallery app `urls.py`, the `gallery_detail` url should be something like just `url('^(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'gallery.views.detail', 'gallery_detail')` instead of `url('^gallery/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'gallery.views.detail', 'gallery_detail')` which is what it would normally be

Comment: Exact line from urls.py is: `url(r'^(?P<gallery_id>\d+)/$','list', name='gallery_details'),`